# R Grep file name for a variable

Tags: r, regex, file

I am new to R so I am struggling with what I imagine is a fairly simple question. For this question I am not looking for someone to give me just a solution. I was hoping that someone could explain the answer to me, so that I might learn to do it myself, rather than just copy what it is you have done. That being said, here is my problem and questions.

I am making a histogram with R. A user will submit a file and data from that file will be used to make a histogram. That much is already set and done. Where I am having a problem is that I need to take only part of that file name and use it to help make a title for the histogram. The file name is a bit of a monster and follows this naming convention:

> X_Y.doc.Z.x_y_z

The aspects of that file name that I need are the Y and Z. I know that many people use grep but I am not sure how to use it in this instance. I have already read the ??grep page and am familiar with the basics of grep but don't really know where to start.

Eventually I will also need to grep some information from an excel file, if someone cares to advise me in that matter as well.
If it helps, this is how I am accepting the files:

```
F.n<-(tk_choose.files(default="", caption="Select a file", multi=TRUE, filters=NULL, index=1))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You were on the right track to read `?grep`, but `?regex` will be more helpful.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich regex does not have an example on how to use it in the ?regex and I just did a quick search and did not find anything immediately relevant. Do you have any suggestions on where to find more information or a tutorial on this?

Comment: @User the only way I have found to learn `regex` syntax is to fight with it and beat your head against the wall until it starts to become clearer... But when it does its a very powerful tool!

Comment: @Justin Well, I appreciate your honesty in the matter. Lol. I am sure my head will get lots of wall action.

Comment: @Justin, the thing that bothers me about regex is having to think about the different implementations. If you're just using regex with one program, it's not too bad; but, when you start trying to use it in others, and they use different methods for grouping and so on... that's when I feel like beating my head against the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer already given using `stringr` is excellent.  That package provides you with some very helpful string munging tools.

If you want to only use base, you could do this with `gsub`.  Assuming your punctuation stays the same and there will not be any embedded periods or underscores in the X, Y or Z something like this should work

```
f <- 'X_Y.doc.Z.x_y_z'
gsub('^.+_(.+)\\.doc\\.(.+)\\..+_.+$', '\\1 \\2', f)
```

which returns:

```
"Y Z"
```

you could put whatever you want in there though to make it easier to get at each piece or could do this in two lines returning one each.  And remember, R almost never changes data in place.  You need to assign the output of a function to a variable like below.  Otherwise it will just print to the console and be "lost" (this is true *most* of the time).

```
y <- gsub('^.+_(.+)\\.doc\\..+\\..+_.+$', '\\1', f)
z <- gsub('^.+_.+\\.doc\\.(.+)\\..+_.+$', '\\1', f)
```

Lets break it down.

`^` specifies the beginning of a line.  its good to be explicit.  similarly `$` identifies the end of a line.

`.` represents any character and following it with a `+` means one or more of any character. If you used `.*` instead of `.+` it would mean zero or more of any character and that isnt what we want.  If i want to write a normal `.` I need to escape it since its a special character.  `\` is the escape character both for regular expressions and for R.  So... you need two.  To write a normal period you need to write `\\.`

Clear to be sure.  Finally the parentheses represent a group I want to save. They can be referenced later using numbers indicating the order you saved them.  In some languages these parentheses need to be escaped also, but not R.

Comment: So (just to be clear), to use this I would have to set your line of code to some variable such as: yz<- gsub('^.+_(.+)\\.doc\\.(.+)\\..+_.+$', '\\1 \\2', f)? Or as you mentioned I could do it in two by something like this: y<-gsub('^.+_(.+)\\.doc\\..+\\..+_.+$', '\\1 \\2', f) and z<-gsub('^.+_.+\\.doc\\.(.+)\\..+_.+$', '\\1 \\2', f)?

Comment: @User Exactly.  where your string was the variable `f` I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works just as I would expect and you gave a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Grep uses [Regular Expressions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) to search for substrings matching a pattern. For your problem of matching certain elements from a filename, you would probably want to use **capturing groups** to extract the different parts.

An example of a regular expression with a capturing group would be:

```
"Hello, (\w+)"
```

To match strings of the format "Hello, Friend". Here is an explanation of the pattern:

- `\w` will match a "word character", while
- `+` means that at least one, but multiple of them will be matched.
- For the other structural parts of your file name convention, we can just include `_` as they are but have to escape `.` as they have a special meaning in regular expressions.
- To define a group that you want to match (a capturing group), you put the part to be matched in parentheses `(\w+)`

Using all that, we get the following pattern:

```
"(\w+)_(\w+)\.doc\.(\w+)\.(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)"
```

To get the pattern to work in R, we will have to escape all `\` characters as `\\`:

```
> pattern = "(\\w+)_(\\w+)\\.doc\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)"
```

While grep and regex are powerful, I personally prefer the [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package for its simpler interface, in particular the `str_match` function can be very helpful as it will return a matrix with column 1 giving the full match and all subsequent columns giving the matches to the capturing groups:

```
> x = "X_Y.doc.Z.x_y_z"
> str_match(x, pattern)

     [,1]              [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "X_Y.doc.Z.x_y_z" "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "x"  "y"  "z"
```

If you are new to regular expressions, you should be fine with a tutorial for any language such as [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Syntax will mostly be similar, but vary only in details while not all features are supported by all programming languages. If you want to try out your expressions before putting them into your programs, I highly recommend [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: AH, so stringr is a package I would need to install and then import the library as I did with library("tcltk"). Correct?

Comment: Correct. Simply use `install.packages("stringr")`, then `library(stringr)`.

Comment: I like your solution but unfortunately I don't have root privileges on my computer. But when someone who does comes in I will be sure to install this package for the future. Thanks!!

Comment: You can install packages as non-root. They will be placed in your home directory in a R folder, by default. The normal installation procedure should ask you whether the folder should be created the first time you are using it.

Comment: It does ask to make a folder but I am not sure about the policy on such things, and I figure I am better safe than sorry until I can ask. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case of just needing a single letter that is in a well-defined place, `substr` would probably be simpler:

```
> a <- "X_Y.doc.Z.x_y_z"
> substr(a, 3, 3)
[1] "Y"
> substr(a, 9, 9)
[1] "Z"
```